# Firebase automatically scroll listview when data is added

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am working on a chat application and i am using firebase listview ui which works great, but my problem is when data is inserted to the database, the listview does not scroll down automatically and when reopening the listview activity, it starts from the top which i will have to scroll down for minutes to see the new data inserted, can you help me implement this

```
FirebaseListAdapter<Chats> chatsFirebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Chats>(
            this,
            Chats.class,
            R.layout.messaging_layout,
            readMessages
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Chats model, int position) {
            TextView username = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername);
            username.setText(model.getUsername());
            TextView message = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewMessage);
            message.setText(model.getMessage());
            TextView date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate);
            date.setText(model.getDate());
        }
    };
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(chatsFirebaseListAdapter.getCount() -1);
    listView.setAdapter(chatsFirebaseListAdapter);
```

Comment: remove smooth scroll and simply use scrollto

Comment: i did not get what you commented can you describe it for me using some example code

Comment: Post relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to set the scroll to the bottom of the chat

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount() -1);
```

Comment: i have included my code above for you to see if i have used it write

Comment: @JamaMohamed Set the adapter first and then call smoothScrollToPosition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to automatically scroll list to the bottom, no matter what items are currently visible.

listView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);

Comment: sorry but did not wrk

Comment: Suppose if  you know when the list data has changed, you can manually tell the list to scroll to the bottom by setting the list selection to the last row. Like:

private void scrollListViewToBottom() {
    myListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
        }
    });
}

Answer (score 0):

if you are using recyclerView also i better recommend to use recyclerView as its far better than listView

Try this (Recycler View ONLY)

```
listView.scrollToPosition(chatsFirebaseListAdapter.getCount() -1);
```

instead of

`listView.smoothScrollToPosition(chatsFirebaseListAdapter.getCount() -1);` that will prevent scrolling from top to bottom also

If you can listner when firebase get the new mesage and adds to the list
`there also use lv_chatList.scrollToPosition(messagesList.size() - 1);` once the data is loaded to the list

Please comment below if you can't meet your need